# How can I add php to an xml file using .htaccess and make it work?

Tags: php, html, xml

I have this in my XML file

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .xml
```

Which I am using so inside my XML file I can print things from inside a database.
However `<?xml?>` is apparently php and returns a parse error.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What version of `php` you are using, `5` ?

Comment: yep version 5 on my server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it using

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php .xml
```

Also check for `short_open_tag` and make sure it's in `php.ini` file and you are not using it

```
short_open_tag = Off
```

Also, you can write/generate `xml` from a `.php` file using (if this is an option)

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/xml');
    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
?>
<item>
    <title><?php echo "something"; ?></title>
</item>
<?php
    // more php code
?>
```

Comment: im on free hosting, how do I get to the php.ini file

Comment: Then it's not a problem, they must have it set `off`.

Comment: I gave up because see, if I dont use RSS and can't work it, then nobody else in my year will know what it is or use it

Answer (score 1):

I know this is and old question, but while sending an xml header type actually solves the problem, I don't think it answers the question as it was phrased. Instead of placing
`AddType application/x-httpd-php .xml`
in the actual xml file, try adding
`AddType application/x-httpd-php .xml`
to your .htaccss file.
This should clear up your problem.  Happy coding!